# Replacing character with another one upon validation

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a simple hangman game. The part I'm really struggling with is if the user picks a correct letter it should replace the underscores in `secretWord` with the letters the user picked Ex: `wordPicked = ‘ROOT’` (`randomWord` return) if user clicks on 'O' button it should return `_ O O _` but my code currently returns 
’O O O O’.

So back to `ROOT` as the example `wordPicked = ‘ROOT’`, `wordPickedlength = 4`, `secretWord.length = 8`. because of the repeat function I added with will be ("_ ") so the length of that will be 4 characters. I'm really confused as to how to match O in the indices values of (1, 2) in `wordPicked` to the corresponding `wordPicked` indices values at (2, 4). The part where I try and write the algorithm is near the bottom of my validation function, it is only this part that I really need help with.

```
// Const Variables
    const Words = [“ROOT”, “FOOD”, “APPLE”, “GRAPES"];

const validate = function(event){
    const element = event.target 
    let letter = pushedElement.innerText;

    //Checking whether the letter clicked by the user is actually in the //word

        // Need help here
        if (wordPicked.includes(letter) == true) {

          for (let i = 0; i < wordPicked.length; i++) {
            if (wordPicked.charAt(i) == letter) {
              replaceSecretWord = secretWord.replace(/_/g, letter);
            }

            document.querySelector("#word").innerText = replaceSecretWord;

          }

}
```

Comment: `const letterX = new RegExp('[^'+letter+']', 'gi'); let output = selectedWord.replace(letterX, '_');`

Comment: I would hold the letter choices in an Array, so your code may be some variation of: `const letters = document.querySelectorAll('letters'), choices = []; for(let i=0,l=letters.length; i<l; i++){ letters[i].onclick = function(){ const v = this.textContent; if(choices.indexOf(v) === -1)choices.push(v);  const letterX = new RegExp('[^'+choices.join('')+']', 'gi'); outputElement.textContent = selectedWord.replace(letterX, '_'); }`

Comment: Yeah... that's not quite the same. Keep studying. You'll get it.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: Editing Questions to improve them (e.g. clarification, adding additional information, etc.) *is encouraged*. However, editing a Question to change it into a different question, which results in invalidating one or more Answers, is against policy on Stack Overflow. Your edit here did so. The policy is that other users with edit privileges should proactively revert such changes. I have done so here. You *are encouraged to [ask a new Question](/questions/ask)*, perhaps with a link to this one for additional context. We want to help, but your new/additional issue needs to be a new Question.

Comment: I appreciate that you're trying to clarify your question. I agree there was a considerable amount of extra code in your original version which detracted a bit from what you were asking. However, both of the answers here talk to some of the specifics of your original question, which you've now removed. That makes the answers sound like they are (at least) a bit off (i.e. that they are answering a different question, which they are). As such, your more recent edit appears to have at least partially invalidated the answers, which is something that's really not supposed to be done.

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm new to stack overflow not really sure of how the ideal practices on posting/editing questions but i'm sure that will come with time. The main thing I needed was the function as that was the hardest part for me to wrap my head around. I know 100% my code prior to this was functional just a lot of jargon. So if I were to refer back to my own post at some point or others I wanted to make my question go straight to the point instead of answering a specific question. As I'm trying to understand the concepts not a solution to a specific problem.

Comment: @bob SO doesn't take much to get used to.  I recommend taking the "tour" again -- it's in the menu when you click the question mark in your nav bar.  In it, you might find that the actions which spoked controversy was changing your title and question to literal gibberish, changing the tag from `javascript` to `c++`, and leaving your reason as "Because I wanted to".  In that case, a deletion might be your best option.  For using it here, votes don't hurt you.  Vote-up any question or answer you find helpful or well written; downvote items that don't make sense or are out of place for the forum.

Answer (score 1):

There were a few things still missing in your code, like setting the `onclick` for the button and the letters.
I copied your game to codepen and finished the `letterPressed` function https://codepen.io/wutzig/pen/ZEGpOVE

One way to do it is just splitting the secret word into on array, substituting the correct letters and joining the array back to the secret word.

```
const wordArr = secretWord.split(' ');
for (let i = 0; i < selectedWord.length; i++) {
  if (selectedWord.charAt(i) == letter) {
    wordArr[i] = letter;
  }
}
secretWord = wordArr.join(' ')
document.querySelector("#word").innerText = secretWord;
```

Answer (score 1):

While the approach to structuring your JavaScript is not one I would recommend for gameplay, I can offer this contribution: it seems that you need a method that accepts the selected character, the secret word, and the currently completed word. When the provided character matches those in the secret word, the completed word is modified.

[Repl Example](https://repl.it/repls/GenerousSophisticatedBusinesssoftware)

```
const testCharacter = (character, secretWord, completedWord) => {
  let secretWordArray = secretWord.split('')
  return secretWordArray
    .reduce((_secretWord, secretCharacter, secretCharacterIndex) => {
      if(secretCharacter === character) {
        _secretWord.completedWord.splice(secretCharacterIndex, 1, character)
        _secretWord.matches ++
      }
      if(secretCharacterIndex === secretWordArray.length - 1) {
        _secretWord.completedWord = _secretWord.completedWord.join('')
      }
      return _secretWord
    }, {
      character: character,
      completedWord: completedWord.split(''),
      matches: 0,
    })
}
```

```
// M____tt__
{ character: 'a', completedWord: 'Ma__atta_', matches: 3 }
{ character: 'q', completedWord: 'Ma__atta_', matches: 0 }
{ character: 'n', completedWord: 'Man_attan', matches: 2 }
{ character: 'h', completedWord: 'Manhattan', matches: 1 }
```

Each time a word is selected, you could run a method like this one and store the results in different variables. You will probably want to add other methods for creating a maximum number of attempts, current number of attempts, assigning points for matches, etc...

Answer (score 1):

## Secret Word

---

### TOC

1. Prequel
2. Using secretWord (w/o regex)

   1. Example Snippet
3. Only using selectedWord (and tracking selections)

   1. Example Snippet

---

### Prequel

There are a few things to keep in mind:

- A regex replace with 'g' flag will replace all occurrences of the match.  The code in question was trying to match all underscore-space combinations.  Instead of using regex, it would be easier to replace at the position of the `secretWord` when it does not contain spaces -- essentially, the same as the secret word; and then you could easily populate spaces back
- below in the code, there are also two calls to display the secret word; first on the initial click, but also on an unmatched (wrong) selection
- another option might not be to use the `secretWord` at all, but instead only use the selected word.  I'll display both examples below

---

### Using secretWord (w/o regex)

The `/_/g` in the original code was replacing all existing underscores in `secretWord` with the same [selected] letter.  This accounts for why the letter appeared multiple times.

If the selected word is "ROME" (with `secretWord == '_ _ _ _'`) and you selected the letter "O", the regex would replace *all* underscores with "O", not only the 2nd-position (where it letter exists in `ROME`).  That offending line requires re-work.

Below, you'll see the regex was replaced with:

```js
secretWord    = secretWord.trim().split(' ');
secretWord[i] = letter;
secretWord    = secretWord.join(' ')
replaceSecretWord = secretWord
```

The first line serves two functions:

1. removes the trailing space with `trim()`
2. makes an array of only underscores (e.g., `['_','_','_','_']`) by splitting on the space character

What's left is the same number of elements (underscores) as letters in the `selectedWord` (word being guessed). More importantly, the same length means they have a sync'd index.  So the underscore in `secretWord` can be replaced by the matched letter at the same index of the `selectedWord` and the for-loop and if-statement are already determining that matched index.

Once the secret word index (`secretword[i]`) has been replaced, it might look something like (`['_','O','_','_']`), which means it just needs to be converted back to a string, with spaces in between for display.  This is accomplished with joining the array on a space: `.join(' ')`.

#### Example Snippet

```js
// Const Variables
const POSSIBLE_WORDS = ["TORONTO", "PARIS", "ROME", "MISSISSIPPI"];

// Global Variables
let selectedWord = "";
let randNum;
let maxWordSize = POSSIBLE_WORDS.length;
let secretWordLength;
let secretWord;
let replaceSecretWord;


const startGame = function(event) {

  // selectedWord is chosen by the chooseRandomWord Function
  selectedWord = chooseRandomWord();

  console.log(`random number: ${randNum}`);
  console.log(`Selected word: ${selectedWord}`);

  // Showing the appropriate of dashes based on number picked
  secretWordLength = selectedWord.length;
  secretWord = "_ ".repeat(secretWordLength);

  document.querySelector("#word").innerText = secretWord;  // <= don't forget first display*
}

const chooseRandomWord = function() {
  randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxWordSize);

  let randomWord = "";

  switch (randNum) {
    case 0:
      randomWord = "TORONTO";
      break;

    case 1:
      randomWord = "PARIS";
      break;

    case 2:
      randomWord = "ROME";
      break;

    case 3:
      randomWord = "MISSISSIPPI";
      break;
  }

  return randomWord;
}

const letterPressed = function(event) {

  const pushedElement = event.target

  if (pushedElement.classList.contains("letter") === false) {
    console.log("Ignoring your click. Reason: you didn't click on a <div class='letter'> element")
    return;
  }

  if (pushedElement.classList.contains("already-selected")) {
    console.log("You already selected this letter!");
    return;
  }

  pushedElement.classList.add("already-selected");

  let letter = pushedElement.innerText;
  console.log("You clicked on: " + letter);
  document.querySelector("#results").innerText = "You clicked on: " + letter;

  let resultsLabel = document.querySelector("#results");

  //Checking whether the letter clicked by the user is actually in the word
  if (selectedWord.includes(letter)) {

    resultsLabel.innerText = `Correct, ${letter} is in the word`;
    console.log(`Correct, ${letter} is in the word`);

    replaceSecretWord = secretWord // <= don't forget your default case*
    for (let i = 0; i < selectedWord.length; i++) {
      if (selectedWord.charAt(i) == letter) {
        // was: replaceSecretWord = secretWord.replace(/_/g, letter);
        // now:
        secretWord    = secretWord.trim().split(' ');
        secretWord[i] = letter;
        secretWord    = secretWord.join(' ')
        replaceSecretWord = secretWord
      }

      document.querySelector("#word").innerText = replaceSecretWord;

    }
  }
}

$('.letter-bank').on('click', letterPressed)
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #7a7a7a;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.letter {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.letter:hover {
  border: 1px solid #555;
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Gets applied when button is clicked */

.already-selected {
  background-color: grey;
  cursor: default;
}


/* Styling for _ _ _ section*/

div#word {
  font-size: 26px;
  padding: 20px;
}

span.chancesLabel {
  color: #1d8f50;
  font-weight: 600;
}

img {
  max-width: 100px;
}


/* generic css style to hide elements */

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.pretty-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 38px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 38px;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.blue {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #33C3F0;
  border-color: #33C3F0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  color: #363636;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}

.subtitle {
  color: #7a7a7a;
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

div.row {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="container">
  <!--             Start Game Button & Header                                 -->
  <h1>HangPerson Game</h1>
  <button class="btn-start-game pretty-btn blue" onclick="startGame()"> (RE)Start Game </button> <br>


  <!-- @DEBUG: Used for debugging purposes -->
  <div id="debug-actual-word">
    <!-- Random word will be displayed here -->
  </div>

  <!--   Main UI for the game    -->
  <!-- hangperson picture -->
  <div class="image-container">
    <img id="img-hangperson-status" src="img/001-pic.png">
  </div>

  <!--  UI for showing state of the word -->
  <h2>Your word is:</h2>
  <div id="word">
    please press start game button
  </div>

  <!-- # of gusses left -->
  <div id="chances">
    Chances Remaining: <span class="chancesLabel">????</span>
  </div>

  <!-- Msg for wrong/correct letter picked -->
  <div id="results">
    <!-- If letter in word show correct message -->
    <!-- Otherwise show error msg -->
  </div>


  <!--    UI for letter "buttons" not buttons actually div        -->
  <h2>Guess a Letter</h2>

  <!-- Required to detect clicks on individual button -->
  <div class="letter-bank">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="letter">A</div>
      <div class="letter">B</div>
      <div class="letter">C</div>
      <div class="letter">D</div>
      <div class="letter">E</div>
      <div class="letter">F</div>
      <div class="letter">G</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="letter">H</div>
      <div class="letter">I</div>
      <div class="letter">J</div>
      <div class="letter">K</div>
      <div class="letter">L</div>
      <div class="letter">M</div>
      <div class="letter">N</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="letter">O</div>
      <div class="letter">P</div>
      <div class="letter">Q</div>
      <div class="letter">R</div>
      <div class="letter">S</div>
      <div class="letter">T</div>
      <div class="letter">U</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="letter">V</div>
      <div class="letter">W</div>
      <div class="letter">X</div>
      <div class="letter">Y</div>
      <div class="letter">Z</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- //. letter-bank -->
</body>
```

---

### Only using selectedWord (and tracking selections)

The strategy here requires two things.  First you must keep track of your selected letters.  You could query the page each time, or easier is to store an array (in the example, `selectedLetters`).

The other part is to only use the word being guessed and after each guess, convert all the non-matched (not guessed) letters in it to an underscore.  This is accomplished with:

```js
let re = new RegExp('[^' + selectedLetters.join('') + ']', 'g')
document.querySelector("#word").innerText = selectedWord.replace(re,'_').split('').join(' ');
```

It builds a regex of letters that should not be made an underscore.  It doesn't matter if it contains bad letters, because those letters don't exist in the word in the first place.  This mean that if your word is "ROME", and you guessed "O", the regex would look like `/[^O]/g`. So when it comes to replacing the letters that aren't an "O" in "ROME" with an underscore, it would look like "_O__".  If the next guess was "A" it'd look like `/[^OA]/g` and when it replaced non-"O" and non-"A" in "ROME", it'd still be left with "_O__", demonstrating it doesn't matter that "A" wasn't in "ROME".

The other important thing here is that `.replace()` does not mutate the string it is being acted on.  That means although the `selectedWord` is being used, none of the letters in it are ever being replaced.  The underscores are generated for each turn.  This may not be the most efficient way to handle it, but this a good case of something that does not need to be over-optimized.

#### Example Snippet

```js
// Const Variables
const POSSIBLE_WORDS = ["TORONTO", "PARIS", "ROME", "MISSISSIPPI"];

// Global Variables
let selectedWord = "";
let selectedLetters = [];
let randNum;
let maxWordSize = POSSIBLE_WORDS.length;


const startGame = function(event) {

  // selectedWord is chosen by the chooseRandomWord Function
  selectedWord = chooseRandomWord();

  console.log(`random number: ${randNum}`);
  console.log(`Selected word: ${selectedWord}`);

  document.querySelector("#word").innerText = selectedWord.replace(/./g,'_ ');  // <= don't forget first display*
}

const chooseRandomWord = function() {
  randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxWordSize);

  let randomWord = "";

  switch (randNum) {
    case 0:
      randomWord = "TORONTO";
      break;

    case 1:
      randomWord = "PARIS";
      break;

    case 2:
      randomWord = "ROME";
      break;

    case 3:
      randomWord = "MISSISSIPPI";
      break;
  }

  return randomWord;
}

const letterPressed = function(event) {

  const pushedElement = event.target

  if (pushedElement.classList.contains("letter") === false) {
    console.log("Ignoring your click. Reason: you didn't click on a <div class='letter'> element")
    return;
  }

  if (pushedElement.classList.contains("already-selected")) {
    console.log("You already selected this letter!");
    return;
  }

  pushedElement.classList.add("already-selected");

  let letter = pushedElement.innerText;
  console.log("You clicked on: " + letter);
  document.querySelector("#results").innerText = "You clicked on: " + letter;
  selectedLetters.push(letter)

  let resultsLabel = document.querySelector("#results");
  
  // regex of selected letter (the "^" signifies an not-match)
  let re = new RegExp('[^' + selectedLetters.join('') + ']', 'g')
  
  // replace all not-matched in the word with underscores (leaving all matched letters visible/exposed)
  document.querySelector("#word").innerText = selectedWord.replace(re,'_').split('').join(' ');

}

$('.letter-bank').on('click', letterPressed)
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #7a7a7a;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.letter {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.letter:hover {
  border: 1px solid #555;
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Gets applied when button is clicked */

.already-selected {
  background-color: grey;
  cursor: default;
}


/* Styling for _ _ _ section*/

div#word {
  font-size: 26px;
  padding: 20px;
}

span.chancesLabel {
  color: #1d8f50;
  font-weight: 600;
}

img {
  max-width: 100px;
}


/* generic css style to hide elements */

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.pretty-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 38px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 38px;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.blue {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #33C3F0;
  border-color: #33C3F0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  color: #363636;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}

.subtitle {
  color: #7a7a7a;
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

div.row {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="container">
  <!--             Start Game Button & Header                                 -->
  <h1>HangPerson Game</h1>
  <button class="btn-start-game pretty-btn blue" onclick="startGame()"> (RE)Start Game </button> <br>


  <!-- @DEBUG: Used for debugging purposes -->
  <div id="debug-actual-word">
    <!-- Random word will be displayed here -->
  </div>

  <!--   Main UI for the game    -->
  <!-- hangperson picture -->
  <div class="image-container">
    <img id="img-hangperson-status" src="img/001-pic.png">
  </div>

  <!--  UI for showing state of the word -->
  <h2>Your word is:</h2>
  <div id="word">
    please press start game button
  </div>

  <!-- # of gusses left -->
  <div id="chances">
    Chances Remaining: <span class="chancesLabel">????</span>
  </div>

  <!-- Msg for wrong/correct letter picked -->
  <div id="results">
    <!-- If letter in word show correct message -->
    <!-- Otherwise show error msg -->
  </div>


  <!--    UI for letter "buttons" not buttons actually div        -->
  <h2>Guess a Letter</h2>

  <!-- Required to detect clicks on individual button -->
  <div class="letter-bank">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="letter">A</div>
      <div class="letter">B</div>
      <div class="letter">C</div>
      <div class="letter">D</div>
      <div class="letter">E</div>
      <div class="letter">F</div>
      <div class="letter">G</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="letter">H</div>
      <div class="letter">I</div>
      <div class="letter">J</div>
      <div class="letter">K</div>
      <div class="letter">L</div>
      <div class="letter">M</div>
      <div class="letter">N</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="letter">O</div>
      <div class="letter">P</div>
      <div class="letter">Q</div>
      <div class="letter">R</div>
      <div class="letter">S</div>
      <div class="letter">T</div>
      <div class="letter">U</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="letter">V</div>
      <div class="letter">W</div>
      <div class="letter">X</div>
      <div class="letter">Y</div>
      <div class="letter">Z</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- //. letter-bank -->
</body>
```

Comment: I have minor reservations about helping an OP after their post vandalisation, but I should keep in mind that posts this informative will be helpful for future readers too. Great work, Mike!

Comment: @halfer I agree. I mostly answered because I had already gone through the process of understanding what was being asked before realizing the vandalization occurred. I may have even started to answer before it had been vandalized, thought I haven't checked the timeline. That said, I'm not a fan of OP's account history, so this is more for future readers.  And thank you so much!